# square bracket in tikz node annotation makes XeLaTeX compilation failed

Tags: latex

[The same question posted by myself in Tex StackExchange Community](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/686906/297890)

When I'm using tikz to draw graph with text annotation, I've met a problem that simply adding "[]" around text in annoation would make the compilation using XeLaTeX fail.

For example, this code works as expect:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \node[draw,align=center] (n) at (0,0) {line1 \\ line2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It generates a box within which shows two lines of text.

But when it becomes as follow, simply add "[ ]", it failed:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \node[draw,align=center] (n) at (0,0) {line1 \\ [line2]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This confused me a lot and I wonder why this would happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `\\` actually can have an optional argument which can be used to adjust the line spacing, e.g. `\\[1cm]`. Latex this thinks that your `[...]` would contain such an optional argument and then gets confused because `line2` is not a length.

You can avoid this by placing something else between the `\\` and the `[`, e.g. a empty group `{}` should do no harm and avoids the problem:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \node[draw,align=center] (n) at (0,0) {line1 \\{} [line2]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. May I ask for a further explaination about why it works and why the origin version didn't?

Comment: @Lucida I added some explanation